# MongoDB\Driver\Manager connection php with parametres

Tags: php, mongodb, parameters, connection

i spend alot of time to find in solution to connect mongogb with setting.

when i connecting into console its works

```
**mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --host 127.0.0.1 --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism "PLAIN" -u username-p**
```

but when i using by php

```
**$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://username:userpasword@127.0.0.1:27017/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=external&gssapiServiceName=mongodb");**
```

i always getting error

> No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Server
>   closed connection. calling ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017']

How i can fix it? what i missing ?

thank you in advance

Comment: isn't `ssl` missing in the second one?  If that is the case, the mongod server should have logged a message about the connection not using SSL

Comment: Thank you,  Joe,  when i put MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://u:p@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname?ssl=true&authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=external");      i get error  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster.. i am in real stuck

Comment: That is a certificate validation failure, do you also need to use `sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true`?